# Python: Get the list of empty files plus non-empty latest files

Tags: python, python-2.6

Files in my folder:
File pattern - `<ABC>_<123>_<CURRENT_DATE>.csv`

```
Example:
1.
  ABC_123_20180802 - Empty File
  ABC_123_20180730 - Empty File
  ABC_123_20180725 - Non-Empty File 

2.  
  EFG_456_20180802 - Empty File
  ABC_456_20180601 - Non-Empty File
```

Our Python version is 2.6 and would like to print two things.

1.The list of empty files(csv) in a folder for a particular day.
Started this for empty files listing:

```
path="C:\Users\\"
for f in os.listdir(path):
    file=path+'\\'+f
    if (os.stat(file).st_size == 0):
        print(file)

Expected Output:
    ABC_123_20180802 - File Empty
    EFG_456_20180802 - File Empty
```

2.In case if current day files are empty then list the last non-empty files(latest date).

```
Expected Output:
    ABC_123_20180725 - File Non-Empty
    ABC_456_20180601 - File Non-Empty
```

How to list empty files for a give date in a folder ?
Second, how to find all the latest non-empty files (any date) in a folder?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: That's not a question. Please understand that SO is a Q&A site. If you do not ask a question (with a question mark, "?"), you will not get an answer.

Comment: Ok, updated my question!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are already using all the tools needed to answer your question.

```
latest_non_empty = None
path="C:\Users\\"
for f in os.listdir(path):
    file=path+'\\'+f
    if (os.stat(file).st_size > 0):
        if latest_none_empty:
            if lastest_none_empty[0] < os.stat(file).st_mtime:
                latest_non_empty_file = (os.stat(file).st_mtime, file)
        else:
            latest_non_empty_file = (os.stat(file).st_mtime, file)
```

Comment: Thanks @@AdriVelaz but I'm getting this error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in <module>
AttributeError: 'nt.stat_result' object has no attribute 'mtime'`

Comment: Should I use `st_mtime` instead?

Comment: Yup sorry typo!.Updated answer

Comment: Just one more thing, how does this variable `lastest_none_empty[0]` get the value? I'm confused here

Comment: I added this to the code `latest_non_empty = None` and it gets set as a tuple with whatever the lastest file is.
`latest_non_empty_file = (os.stat(file).st_mtime, file)`

Comment: So all these different variables in your code are same then?
`latest_non_empty`,`latest_non_empty_file`,`lastest_none_empty`

Comment: Yup there the same. Another typo.